# Why is my logout funciontality being rejected?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to do a logout functionality with redux toolkit but as the function is being dispatched it is coming rejected with the error message `cannot read property of undefined`.

This is my component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Container, AppBar, Toolbar, styled, InputBase, Button } from '@mui/material'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { logoutUser } from '../../reducers/auth/authSlice'


const Search = styled("div")(({theme}) => ({
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: "10px",
    borderRadius: "10px",
    width: "40%"
}))



export default function Navbar() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.user.isAuthenticated);
  const handleLogout = () => {
    dispatch(logoutUser());
    console.log(isAuthenticated)
  };


  return (
    <AppBar position='static' color='primary'>
        <Container>
            <Toolbar>
                <Search>
                    <InputBase placeholder='Search...' fullWidth={true}/>
                </Search>
                    {isAuthenticated ? <Button
                    type='submit' 
                    variant="contained" 
                    color="primary"
                    onClick={handleLogout}
                    >
                    Logout
                    </Button> : ''}
                   
            </Toolbar>
        </Container>
    </AppBar>
  )
}
```

I want to render the logout button in my navbar only if the user isAuthenticated, and as i click the logout button the handleLogout which dispatches the logoutUser action is triggered. The issue is that is being rejected i don´t know why.

So i assume it has to do with my slice and how i am developing the function,

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import setAuthToken from '../../utils/setAuthToken';

import axios from 'axios';

const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem('item'),
    isAuthenticated: false,
    loading: true,
    user: null,
    error: null
}

export const loadUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/loadUser',
  async ({ rejectWithValue }) => {

    if(localStorage.token){
      setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }

    try {
      const res = axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/auth');
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
)

export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/registerUser',
  async (newUser, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      };
      const body = JSON.stringify(newUser);
      const response = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/users',
        body,
        config
      );
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);


export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk('auth/login', async ({ email, password }, { dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
  const body = { email, password };

  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  try {
    const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/auth', body, config);

    dispatch(loadUser());
    console.log(body)
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
  }
});

export const logoutUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/logout',
  async (_, { getState, rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      // Remove token from local storage
      localStorage.removeItem('token');

      // Reset authentication state
      const state = getState();
      state.user.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.user.token = null;
      state.user.user = null;

      return true;
    } catch (err) {
      return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
    }
  }
);




export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [registerUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },
    [registerUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = null;
      
    },
    [registerUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
    [loadUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },
    [loadUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
      state.user = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = false;
    },
    [loadUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.error = action.payload;

    },
    [loginUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },
    [loginUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.token = localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
      state.loading = false;
      state.user = action.payload.user;
    },
    [loginUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
    [logoutUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },
    [logoutUser.fulfilled]: (state) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.token = null;
      state.user = null;
    },
    [logoutUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    }
  }
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const {  } = userSlice.actions


export default userSlice.reducer
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you mentioned what exactly is undefined.

Comment: `"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')"` @DaveNewton

Comment: And that happens where, exactly? Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: It is clearly explained when it is happening. As i click in the logout button, which triggers the handleLogout function, which dispatches the logoutUser that is a function in the userSlice, which has 3 possible cases pending, fulfilled, and rejected. And as the function catches the error of `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data)` the case is rejected.

Comment: Can you just do `return rejectWithValue(err);` inside logoutUser function?  I wanna know exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

The only place where the `data` property is accessed on something in the `handleLogout` function is the following line in the `logoutUser` function:

```js
      return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
```

(next time, I would recommend you provide a **minimal** reproduction example and/or the error stack trace, so others can find it quicker).

This suggests that your code throws some error, which gets caught by the `catch` block. However, `err.response` is `undefined`, which means that `err` is not an Axios error, despite what your error handler expects.

A better way to write this line would be:

```js
      return rejectWithValue(err.response?.data ?? err.message);
```

This ensures that you don't access nonexistent nested properties and that there is always an argument passed to `rejectWithValue`.

Afterwards, you can inspect your actual error and find out why your code throws it.